# Do JMenuBars not work with setComponentZOrder()?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jmenubar

This is a testing class, and I have two JPanels and a JMenuBar (I have overridden the classes while testing something else, these classes DO work). Unfortunately, when I try to use setComponentZOrder(), the JMenuBar doesnt show up anymore. When the setComponentZOrder() portion is commented out, it works out just fine.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
    import java.awt.*;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;

    public class Main extends JFrame
    {
        Panel test1 = new Panel(Color.GREEN);
        Panel test2 = new Panel(Color.BLUE);
        Menuuuuu menuBar = new Menuuuuu();

        public static void main (String []args)
        {   
            new Main();
        }

        public Main()
        {
            super();
            setSize(500,500);
            Container c = getContentPane();
            c.setLayout(null);
            c.setBackground(Color.white);

            test1.setBounds(0,0,500,500);
            c.add (test1);

            test2.setBounds(0,0,500,500);
            c.add(test2);

            setJMenuBar(menuBar);
            setComponentZOrder(test1,0);
            setComponentZOrder(test2,1);
            setVisible(true);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
setComponentZOrder(test1,0);
setComponentZOrder(test2,1);
```

You are setting the ZOrder of components on the frame.

You want to set the ZOrder of components on the content pane:

```
c.setComponentZOrder(test1,0);
c.setComponentZOrder(test2,1);
```